# How do you add a WCF service reference with a fixed port?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0, service-reference

I have a WCF service being hosed by a Windows Service with this in the `app.config`

```
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="AgileServer.AgileService">
      <endpoint address="AgileService" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttp" contract="AgileServer.AgileService" />
      <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:24453/AgileService" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
```

When I try to add a service reference to my service (by clicking "Discover" in the "Add Service Reference" prompt), the URI shows up as `http://localhost:33908/AgileService.svc` I want my service to use `http://localhost:24453/AgileService` as the URI.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to

- have the WCF service in your Windows service up and running
- do not click on `Discover`, but instead type in / paste in the URL you want to connect to - either use the base address (`http://localhost:24453/AgileService`) or the MEX endpoint's address (`http://localhost:24453/AgileService/mex`)

Doing this will connect to the URL defined, and the service metadata will be retrieved and used to create a client-side proxy for the service.

Just as a side-note: your *actual* service URL will be:

```
http://localhost:24453/AgileService/AgileService
```

made up of your base address (`http://localhost:24453/AgileService`) *plus* the relative address on the endpoint (`AgileService`).

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  Is it ever appropriate to use Discover, then?  Will the Service References it creates always be only usable for local testing?

Comment: @Eric: I never use "Discover" myself - not sure what it should really help you with...... The service reference creating is a full-blown, production-ready client - it's definitely **not just** for testing! It creates the client-side config - but you can of course tweak that (use a different URL) for production - but the client code created is *the real thing* - not just for testing!